# How and when is the token refreshed when using BMS Client, and is there a way to force the refresh?

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

We are using:

```
BMSClient.getInstance().registerAuthenticationListener("realm", new CustomAuthentication(this));
```

and:

```
AuthorizationManager.createInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
AuthorizationManager.getInstance().setAuthorizationPersistencePolicy(AuthorizationManager.PersistencePolicy.ALWAYS);
```

to store the authorization data on the phone. "The authorization data will be saved on local storage" is set to ALWAYS.

The code above is always run on our splashscreen on startup so it is always run when the app restarted.

The problem we have had is that after some time (hours or days) when what we suspect the token has expired we get response in the form of **HTTP 307**. Even after restarting the app we keep getting this response on our requests. The only way to get around it is to go into the app from settings and clear all data.

The following questions would help us go forward in our testing and possible solution:

1. How long is the token cached in BMSClient? (testing purposes)
2. Can AuthorizationManager help us in any way to force a new fetch of token?
3. Are they working on log out functionality?

Our custom listener:

```
public class CustomAuth implements AuthenticationListener {

    private Context activityContext;

    public CustomAuth(Context activityContext) {
        this.activityContext = activityContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationChallengeReceived(AuthenticationContext authContext, JSONObject challenge, Context context) {
        //1. read the challenge JSONObject
        //2. handle the challenge (use the context for handling UI based operations)
        //3. return response using the AuthenticationContext authContext
        SharedPreferences preferences = activityContext.getSharedPreferences("UserPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String email = preferences.getString("email", "");
        if(email.equals("")) {
            email = "unidentified-user@error.com";
        }
        JSONObject jsonEmail = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonEmail.put("email", email);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            authContext.submitAuthenticationChallengeAnswer(null);
        }
        authContext.submitAuthenticationChallengeAnswer(jsonEmail);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(Context context, JSONObject info) {
        //additional operations in case of authentication success
        Log.d("Authentication", "Auth success: " + String.valueOf(info));
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(Context context, JSONObject info) {
        //additional operations in case of authentication failure
        Log.d("Authentication", "Auth failure ." + String.valueOf(info));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using AuthorizationManager.clearAuthorizationData() API when 307 is received and resending the request?

Comment: Yes, and we have tried setting the policy to AuthorizationManager.getInstance().setAuthorizationPersistencePolicy(AuthorizationManager.PersistencePolicy.NEVER); that does the same thing since clearAuthorizationData() only clears local data.

Comment: can you check what version of SDK you're using?

Comment: //dependency IBM
    compile 'com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android:push:1.0.2'
    compile group: 'com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android',
            name: 'core',
            version: '1.1.0',
            ext: 'aar',
            transitive: true

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1) The authorization token will be cached indefinitely. The token expires after a 60 minute time period, but will remain cached until a new token is obtained.

It is best practice to obtain a new token once the original token has expired. This can be accomplished by running a new authorization challenge once the previous token has expired.

2) You can always use AuthorizationManager to obtain a new token once the previous token has expired by accessing a protected resource, using obtainAuthorizationHeader, etc.

3) There is currently no way to log out of MCA using the AuthorizationManager. I will speak with the development team about future plans.

In regards to the main problem I see in your question. I would expect you are experiencing this problem because you are attempting to use an expired token against the authorization service. Even though the token is still cached on the device it expired an hour after creation. I would attempt to run a new authorization challenge against the MCA service once the token expires.

If you want to provide your code that may also help me investigate further.

Comment: Added our custom authlistener. We are pretty sure that it might be a problem on your end. What we are experiencing is that the last couple of days all of a sudden the app won't go to protected resources. When looking at the logs we get the log from onAuthFail with the json {"reson":"Login Failed"}. When debugging we can se that it never goes into onAuthChallangeReceived. Then all of a sudden it will receive a challange and all is well. Do you know if you guys have made any updates recently that might be behind this behaviour?

Comment: Can you please provide me with your appID for your Bluemix instance so I can look into the logs

Comment: Our production app-id: 9c877adb-c380-43ce-bb2d-ac9c3d32a04c
Our developer instance app id: 905ce1db-d7b5-41ca-9b4e-a9e1a0695fed
We experience same problem in both instances.

Comment: @enno4859 please provide your appRoute as well. Can you confirm that this is something that happens consistently today? You commented saying that you never receive a challenge, then you do and it works. Is that without clearing all the data from the app? When challenges are not being received are you monitoring the service status page? I wonder if it only happens during intermittent outages

Comment: appRoute for our dev enviroment: wenngarn.eu-gb.mybluemix.net
app-id for dev enviroment: 9c877adb-c380-43ce-bb2d-ac9c3d32a04c

As I write this commet I am experiencing the same behaviour where I am not getting a challange.

03-14 08:57:15.184 18403-24175/? D/WenngarnAuthentication: Auth failure .{"reason":"Login Failed"}
03-14 08:57:15.200 18403-18435/? E/mfpsdk.AuthorizationProcessManager: AuthorizationProcessManager.handleAuthorizationFailure in AuthorizationProcessManager.java:426 :: authorization process failed

Comment: Update, without me doing anything the app all of a sudden now received a new challenge and I got a new token. Time elapsed where it did not receive new token aprox 1 hour.

Comment: @enno4859 The server was working properly. It sounds to me like you had an invalid cached token, thus the 60 min wait before successful auth. When making changes to your client app, be sure to uninstall your previous version before testing. If you don't, you may run into this invalid cached token issue again. If you see this consistent rejection even after uninstalling the previous version, let me know.

Comment: @Jaalger We are currently having this issue in our production application. In other words people that have installed the app and do not make changes to the code and only update their devices when we release updates are experiencing this problem. The problem started a week after the latest release so I am pretty sure it is not on our side. The question becomes again, is there a way to force a challenge to be sent since we know that we get 307 from our back end when this problem occurs, and could then make sure the token is refreshed... Or should we look for a different provider?

Comment: @enno4859 Can you please provide a sample application where I can reproduce the problem. I am unable to reproduce the issue in my environment at the moment. If I can reproduce the issue I should be able to help provide a solution.

Comment: You can download the app from the app-store Wenngarn, and if you tell me what email you register with I can give you access to some protected resources and then it is a matter of waiting since it is very unpredictable (very very hard to recreate).  Unfortunately the app is in swedish but under menu I will give you your own name where the protected resources will be links.

Comment: @enno4859 we really need a sample application so we can run it while using a debugger and looking into the code. The production application will not help us investigate the issue as much.

Comment: I have not been granted permission to submit it publicly, what channels should I use to get it to you? I mean we can send you a debug apk that goes towards our dev enviroment.

Comment: You can email me directly at jaalger@us.ibm.com. Also is this issue only happening on Android? Or is it iOS and Android?